# in Vim is there a way to quickly visually select the file or url under the cursor

Tags: vim

I know that `gf` attempts to open the file under the cursor.  I wondered if there's a way to leverage the filename-recognition portion of `gf` to easily visually select a filename or url under the cursor?

Comment: Do you have a specific usecase? `viW` is usually enough for filenames and URLs.

Comment: Good point!  That is indeed good enough most cases.  I didn't know about W, only w.  Thx

Comment: If you want to select anything inside of quotes you can also use `vi"`.  If you're selecting C-style system includes you can also do `vi<` or `vi>`.

Answer (score 3):

The filename detection of `gf` is powered by the `'isfname'` option. There's also a corresponding regular expression atom `\f`. Therefore, you can search for the current filename under the cursor (a.k.a. `<cfile>`) with:

```
:let @/ = '\f*\%#\f*'
```

In recent Vim 7.3 versions, you can then use the `gn` command to select the match.